# How to map compiled JS errors trace to Typescript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In my project, I have an `/src` folder that contains `.ts` files and I setup `tsconfig.json` to compile those in a folder called `/dist` into `.js` and **source map** `.js.map`.

Now I run the code using the commande `node /dist/whatever.js`
But Let's say there in a error. The error logs maps to the compiled `.js` files.
[image]
How to make it map to the original `.ts` file ? I assume this is possible because that's the use of **source map**.

[image: erro]

Answer (score 1):

Happened to see this question. I didn't really use IntelliJ, but I have been using [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support) to do the trick. You could either programmtically add `import 'source-map-support/register';`, or invoke node CLI `node -r source-map-support/register compiled.js`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using IntelliJ. You can exclude directories so they will not be indexed.

[image]

Comment: How is this mapping the errors trace to the Typescript file ?